# Android decrease or increase the selection position in Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

In my android application I have a Spinner with Items, like: (1,2) (3,4) .. (71,72).
When I select an Item from that Spinner then I get eg. (67,68) out there.
Now I want to programatically change the Selected Item to (65,66) or to
(69,70) with a click on one or another textView.
That is, I want to decrease or increase the selection position in the String Array by clicking on the two textViews, like this:

' <<  SelectedItem  >> ' .

For this I can use setSelection(position).

My application can know which Item is selected so far by using getSelectedItemPosition.

The getSelectedItemPosition returns an integer. So eg. if I decrease that integer and run setSelection(position) with it, the SelectedItem will changed to the previous item in that array.

So for this to work I must add the integer to a 'position_variable',
then decrease that variable with 1 and run setSelection(position_variable) with that value.

The program must verify whether is the position 0 or the maximum value to not go over/under bounds.

How can I achive this in Java? I am developing my application in Android Studio.

In activity_main.xml I have among others followings:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/forward"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/ora_keltezese"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/orarend"
            android:text="@string/forward"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:onClick="increaseSpinnerItemPosition"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/backward"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/ora_keltezese"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/backward"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:onClick="decreaseSpinnerItemPosition"/>
```

In MainActivity.java I have among others followings:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.orarend);
        //Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.TanitasiNapok, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.blokkora);
        //Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.BlokkoraSorszama, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);


        Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.osztaly);
        //Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.OsztalyKivalasztasa, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner3.setAdapter(adapter3);

        }

    public void decreaseSpinnerItemPosition (View v) {
        //What to put here?
    }

    public void increaseSpinnerItemPosition (View v) {
        //What to put here?
    }
}
```

So how can I implement the position_variable in to my application?
How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public void decreaseSpinnerItemPosition (View v) {
    spinner3.setSelection(Math.max(0, spinner3.getSelectedItemPosition() - 1));
}

public void increaseSpinnerItemPosition (View v) {
   spinner3.setSelection(Math.min(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.OsztalyKivalasztasa).length - 1, spinner3.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1));
}
```

`Math.max(x, y)` returns the greater number of x and y. So if x would be 1 and y would be 2, this would return 2. We use it here to not fall below 0. So if `spinner3.getSelectedItemPosition() - 1` would be less (or equal) than 0, `Math.max(0, spinner3.getSelectedItemPosition() - 1)` would return 0. 
The same with Math.min, but in this case we check the upper range value (depending on the array's size).
You can also type

```
if(spinner3.getSelectedItemPosition() - 1 <= 0) {
    spinner3.setSelection(0);
} else {
    spinner3.setSelection(spinner3.getSelectedItemPosition() - 1);
}
```

It would be the same.

And don't forget to define your spinner3 globally:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Spinner spinner3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    [...]
    spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.osztaly);
    [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, it works! Actually I am decreasing or increasing the spinner2. So I modified your commands accordingly. Just do not understand what am I did?

Comment: I edited my answer and simplified the increase and decrease methods.

Comment: Thank you very much for help!!